# 時系列データでラグを取った場合のNAへの対処

Tags: r, tidyverse

http://notchained.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/04/24/223027
を参考にラグをとりたいのですが、解説にもあるようにやはり先頭行がNAになってしまいます。
データフレームの2列目から20000列目までをラグをとりたいですが、2つほど気になる点があります。

1. 新しい列を作りたくないのですが、その場合、`library(tidyverse)`のもとで

   ```
   mutate(a = a - lag(a))
   ```

   でよろしいでしょうか。
2. 先頭行のNAをその次の行の値で埋めたいのですが
   列名が非常に複雑で、番地を指定してループを回す方法で行きたいのですがうまくいきません。
   下のコードではエラーでした。

   ```
   for(i in 2:20000){
   df <- df %>% mutate(df[,i] = df[,i] -lag(df[,i]))
   }

   for (i in 2:20000){df[1,i] <- df[2,i]}
   ```

**追記**
先頭行のNAをその次の行の値で埋めるとはこういう感じです。
投稿を利用させていただきました。

```
df_lag
#>    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#> 1    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> 2     6    5    4    3    2
#> 3     1    1    1    1    1
#> 4     1    1    1    1    1
#> 5     1    1    1    1    1
#> 6     1    1    1    1    1
#> 7     1    1    1    1    1
#> 8     1    1    1    1    1
#> 9     1    1    1    1    1
#> 10    1    1    1    1    1

df_lag[1,] <- df_lag[2,]
df_lag
#>    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#> 1     6    5    4    3    2
#> 2     6    5    4    3    2
#> 3     1    1    1    1    1
#> 4     1    1    1    1    1
#> 5     1    1    1    1    1
#> 6     1    1    1    1    1
#> 7     1    1    1    1    1
#> 8     1    1    1    1    1
#> 9     1    1    1    1    1
#> 10    1    1    1    1    1
```

**追記2**

```
for(i in 2:20000){
 df[,i] <- df[,i] - lag(df[,i])
}
```

を実行するとエラーは出ませんが2:20000列目がすべてNAになってしまいます。

また、エラーは

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"for(i in 2:20000){
df <- df %>% mutate(df[,i] ="
```

でした。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そちらのブログを書いている者です。読んでいただいてありがとうございます。

> 1. 新しい列を作りたくないのですが、その場合

はい、それで大丈夫です。

> 2．先頭行のNAをその次の行の値で埋めたいのですが
>   列名が非常に複雑で、番地を指定してループを回す方法で行きたいのですがうまくいきません。

ちょっとデータの形がよくわからないのですが、こういう感じでしょうか？
質問文のコードでどういうエラーが出たのかも書いていただけるとありがたいです。

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(
  col1 = 1:10,
  col2 = 1:10,
  col3 = 1:10,
  col4 = 1:10,
  col5 = 1:10
)

df_lag <- df %>%
  mutate_all(funs(. - lag(.)))
df_lag
#>    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#> 1    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> 2     1    1    1    1    1
#> 3     1    1    1    1    1
#> 4     1    1    1    1    1
#> 5     1    1    1    1    1
#> 6     1    1    1    1    1
#> 7     1    1    1    1    1
#> 8     1    1    1    1    1
#> 9     1    1    1    1    1
#> 10    1    1    1    1    1

df_lag[1,] <- df_lag[2,]
df_lag
#>    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#> 1     1    1    1    1    1
#> 2     1    1    1    1    1
#> 3     1    1    1    1    1
#> 4     1    1    1    1    1
#> 5     1    1    1    1    1
#> 6     1    1    1    1    1
#> 7     1    1    1    1    1
#> 8     1    1    1    1    1
#> 9     1    1    1    1    1
#> 10    1    1    1    1    1
```

---

追記：

```r
for(i in 2:20000){
  df <- df %>% mutate(df[,i] = df[,i] -lag(df[,i]))
}
```

の部分でエラーが出ているとのことでしたが、こういう感じでやるなら`mutate()`ではなく直接代入すればいいかと思います。

```r
for(i in 2:20000){
  # lag()にはベクトルを渡す必要があるので[[i]]で取り出す
  # 通常のdata.frameなら[,i]でも大丈夫
  df[,i] <- df[[i]] - lag(df[[i]])
}
```

あるいは、もうすこし高度なやり方としては、`mutate_at()`、`mutate_all()`、`mutate_if()`といった関数を使えば複数の列を一気に処理できます。

```r
df %>%
  mutate_at(2:20000, funs(. - lag(.)))
```

このあたりの使い方については、もしご興味があれば以下のスライドをご参照ください。

https://speakerdeck.com/yutannihilation/dplyrzai-ru-men-colwisebian

Comment: ブログ拝見させていただいてます。ありがとうございます。
その次の行＝NAの直下の行です。

また、エラーは"="がunexpectedとかだったような気がします。あまり本質的ではないところで引っかかってそうな気がします…

Comment: エラーについてありがとうございます。追記しました。

Comment: どうにもうまくいきませんでしたのでアドバイスをいただきたいです…
内容は追記2です。

Comment: lag(df[,i])がすべてNAになってしまっているようです…
df[,i]は普通に表示されるのですが。
これはlag関数のバグかなんかでしょうか。
df[,i]のclassは[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"でした。

Comment: tbl_dfでしたか。lag()にはベクトルを渡す必要があるんですが、tbl_dfから列をベクトルとして取り出すには、df[,i]ではなくdf[[i]]、もしくはpull(df, i)とする必要があります（通常のdata.frameとは挙動が異なります）。

Comment: 本当に有難うございます。ブログの著者様本人に解説していただけるとは思いませんでした。
dplyr, 便利だと思って適当に使ってたら細かい仕様があったんですね…
勉強します。

Comment: いえいえー。仕様につまづくことはありますね。また何かあればご質問ください！